SSIS Catalog connection not working in SQL Server Management Studio v20.* for New Job Step
Since SSMS version 20.*, it is not possible to reference a package in an (local or remote) SSIS catalog when creating a job step in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio without proper certificates.
In this case the server is local but there does not seem to be a way to connect to "localhost" and avoid this problem (I tried ., , localhost, 127.0.0.1 ...). In SSMS v19., this works without error and jobs can be created (and later on seen and run from SSMS v20.).
As soon as I enter IP / hostname and click [...] this message appears:

Complete error message:

TITLE: SSIS Execution Properties
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2146893019)
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Connecting to said server without proper certificates via SSMS is no problem since there is an option "Trust server certificate" (which of course is missing in this specific dialog box).
I am looking for a way to work around this issue because I wouldn't want to use SSMS v19.* for the rest of eternity. I tried to follow a Microsoft Guide to share certificates from Server -> client (where SSMS is installed hoping it would check against this certificate) but could not find any certificate server side.
Thanks :)

Please create a post about it on Microsoft feedback site: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/04fe6ee0-3b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

The default self-signed certificate isn't visible in SQL Server Configuration Manager. If you're not prepared to install a trusted Organisation CA-signed certificate on the instance then you could always capture the public key of the existing self-signed one using nmap and install it into your Trusted Root Certificate store.

I just uninstall the ssms and reinstall the ssms 19. All solved.
