SSIS job step fail : Not using SSL certificate but getting error
I deployed my ssis project succesfully into SQL Server (vrsion 16) Integration Services catalog. But when I try to create a new job, the moment I add a step and select the type to SSIS package and package source to ssis catalog, the moment I click browse for package after I enter my server name I get this error

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2146893019)

This is the error log by windows event viewer:

The certificate received from the remote server was issued by an untrusted certificate authority. Because of this, none of the data contained in the certificate can be validated. The TLS connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate.

The SSPI client process is Ssms (PID: 4248).enter image description here
I tried a lot of solutions that I found online but none have worked, please any little help u can spare I'll appreciate as this is for my internship project validation.

Wasn't this question asked a while ago. I think older SSMS version didn't have this problem, so perhaps try that?

Please send me the link if it was solved, I definelty didn't find any solution that proposed an older version

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78425263/ssis-catalog-connection-not-working-in-sql-server-management-studio-v20-for-ne

For now, just use SSMS 19. The issue is documented in the SSSM release note, "Known issues 20.1" section:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16#known-issues-201

@siggemannen and Yitzhak Khabinsky. Thank you so much my friends, can't tell you the relief of finally fixing this with a simple solution after a full day of troubleshooting

@YitzhakKhabinsky perhaps you should post this as an answer? It seems a lot of people are hitting this issue

It is a bug in the SSMS 20 and 20.1.
The issue is officially documented in the SSMS release notes, "Known issues 20.1" section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16#known-issues-201

When creating or modifying an SSIS job step in a SQL Agent job, you
receive the error "A connection was successfully established with the
server, but then an error occurred during the login process.
(provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued
by an authority that is not trusted.) (Framework Microsoft SqlClient
Data Provider)" regardless of whether Optional or Mandatory is
selected for the Encryption property.

For now, until the issue is resolved by Microsoft, use SSMS 19.3 or earlier to create or modify SSIS job steps.

This is now resolved in SSMS 20.2

Integration Services  Resolved error "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" when creating or modifying an Integration Services job step in SQL Agent. See SSMS 20 - certificate error when viewing or editing Agent jobs that run SSIS packages.

